# Отключение конструктора по умолчанию

Tags: c#, wpf, list

Мне нужно как-то отключить *конструктор по умолчанию*, нужно это для того, чтобы поля в классе не "обнулялись".

Хотя возможно это не лучшее решение проблемы, в общем, я в новой форме `Window1 : Window` инициализирую экземпляр класса `MainWindow` в котором и находится моя коллекция, в следствие чего она обнуляется, а мне нужно сохранить ее значения.

Каким образом можно сохранить значение коллекции, и использовать ее в другом классе?

Comment: вы явно чего-то странного хотите. Даже если вы каким-то образом "отключите" конструктор по умолчанию, никакие волшебные ненулевые значения в вашем классе от этого не появятся, а если и появятся, это это будет некий случайный мусор из памяти

Comment: А как сделать так, чтобы я свободно пользовался коллекцией оттуда? Не теряя данных. (я новичок, не очень хорошо разбираюсь в этом)

Comment: какой вид коллекции?

Comment: Коллекция вида List<T>

Comment: а Т это известный тип?

Comment: Да, известный..

Comment: какой, интегральный?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29872/discussion-between-droft1312-and-vitali-petrov).

Comment: @droft1312 вы пожалуйста конкретно объясните, чего именно вы хотите. Ваши не очень внятные и связные объяснения про конструктор и про "я новичок" по умолчанию только сбивают  с толку.

Comment: @DreamChild ,у меня есть класс, и класс-обертка который хранит в себе коллекцию того базового класса, и вот этот класс обертку я инициализирую в MainWindow, а в свою очередь MainWindow инициализирую в Window1. И вот когда я пытаюсь использовать эту коллекцию, оказывается, что она обнулилась.

Answer (score 4):

Ваша коллекция не обнуляется. Вы создаете новых экземпляр класса `MainWindow`, со всем его содержимым - включая новым. Скорее всего примерно так, где-то в `Window1.cs`:

```
MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
```

Вместо этого вам стоит передать или ссылку на существующую коллекцию, или ссылку на весь `MainWindow` при создании `Window1`:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public List<Something> MyList { get; set; }

    public Window1(List<Something> myList)
    {
        this.MyList = myList;

        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

и передавайте ссылку на существующую коллецию при создании `Window1` в коде `MainWindow`, примерно так:

```
Window1 newWindow = new Window1(this.MyCollectionInMainWindow);
newWindow.Show();
```

Answer (score 2):

В дополнение к правильному ответу @PashaPash:

Если вы, как вы пишете, конструируете `MainWindow` в конструкторе `Window1`, то вы получаете **другой экземпляр** `MainWindow`, в котором, понятно, нет установленной вами коллекции. Правильный путь передачи данных в WPF-сущность — через `DataContext`.

Ваш код должен выглядеть так:

```
public class MainVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<SubVM> InnerItems { get; private set; }
    // реализация INPC, если нужно
}

// в коде
var mainVM = new MainVM();
var mainWindow = new MainWindow() { DataContext = mainVM };
var auxWindow = new Window1() { DataContext = mainVM };
```